# How to split a mathematical expression into tokens? (String -> [String])

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, expression

I know my question sounds generic and I didn't really know how to google for such a thing,  so I'll provide examples of what I mean:

```
ghci> splitTok "12 + 564 * (5 - 38) / 223"
["12", "+", "564", "*", "(", "5", "-", "38", ")", "/", "223"]
ghci> splitTok " 5+2-42  *    (46/5 )"
["5", "+", "2", "-", "42", "*", "(", "46", "/", "5", ")"]
```

How could something like that be implemented? Or maybe there is a function in Prelude that does this type of thing?

Comment: One typically uses a lexer (or even parser) like `alex`, `happy`, `parsec`, etc.

Comment: Definitely look into parser-generators for this kind of task.

Comment: For a simple task like this, you can fold the list with a tuple `(cur_token, [parsed_tokens]`.

Comment: Since your language looks like a subset of Haskell, you could reuse the lexer that ships in `base`. Here's a one liner you can paste into GHCi: `splitTok s = head  [ tks | (tks, "") <- Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP.readP_to_S ( Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP.many Text.Read.Lex.hsLex) s ]`. Or, assuming the right imports: `splitTok s = head  [ tks | (tks, "") <- readP_to_S (many hsLex) s ]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems just to group the digits together and removes the space. Try

```
import Data.Char (isSpace, isDigit)
import Data.List (groupBy)

splitTok = groupBy (\x y->isDigit x && isDigit y) . filter (not . isSpace)
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I came up with an ugly hack that does the job. (Unfortunately introduces a bug)

```
import Data.Char (isSpace, isDigit)

strip :: String -> String
strip = filter (not . isSpace)

addSpacing :: String -> String
addSpacing [a] = [a]
addSpacing (x:y:cs)
    | isDigit x && isDigit y = x : addSpacing rest
    | otherwise = x : ' ' : addSpacing rest
  where rest = y : cs

splitTok :: String -> [String]
splitTok = words . addSpacing . strip
```

It fails in producing a correct string of tokens in this example:

```
ghci> splitTok "125 +   12 62 - 12  *( 51/  3)        "
["125","+","1262","-","12","*","(","51","/","3",")"]
```

For most expressions it works fine though:

```
ghci> splitTok "4123-36522+12"
["4123","-","36522","+","12"]
ghci> splitTok "124 *(12 -(4+5*(331/7)))"
["124","*","(","12","-","(","4","+","5","*","(","331","/","7",")",")",")"]
```

Comment: Not to encourage the hackiness, but what if you just got rid of the `strip` beforehand?  `addSpacing` and then let `words` deal with the cruft.